# Broken URL Detected

Tags: facebook-instant-games

My Facebook instant app is approved, when I am switching it to live mode it shows the following error. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

We had something similar with Android. We did remove the Android platform, switched to Live and added the Android platform again. Hopefully something similar does the job for you too.